# Call function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import AuthentificationService from "../../api/AuthentificationService"
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import ModifyUser from "./ModifyUser" ----------> file i import where my function is

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 360,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
}));

export default function CheckboxList(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([0]);

    const handleToggle = value => () => {
        const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
        const newChecked = [...checked];

        if (currentIndex === -1) {
            newChecked.push(value);
        } else {
            newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
        }

        setChecked(newChecked);

        alert(value.email)
    };

    const deleteUser = value => () => {
        AuthentificationService.deleteUser(value.id)
            .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);

        }) .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        handleClickOpen(); ---------> here i would like to call this function from the file ./ModifyUser
    }

    return (
        <List className={classes.root}>
            {props.response.map( test => {

                if (props.response.length <= 1) {

                } else {
                    return (
                        <ListItem key={test} role={undefined} dense button onClick={handleToggle(test)}>
                            <ListItemText primary={`${test.email}`}/>
                            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                                    <DeleteIcon
                                        onClick={deleteUser(test)}
                                    />
                                </IconButton>
                            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                            <ModifyUser/>
                        </ListItem>
                    );
                }
            })}
        </List>
    );
}
```

I would like to call handleClickOpen from the file ./ModifyUser.

The file modify user is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import AuthentificationService from "../../api/AuthentificationService";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    appBar: {
        position: 'relative',
    },
    title: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        flex: 1,
    },
}));

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

export default function FullScreenDialog() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    let username = "";
    let email = "";
    let password = "";

    function handleClickOpen() {   ---------> i would like to call this function
        setOpen(true);
    }

    function handleClose() {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    /// Set the state when the texfield change
    function textFieldChange(e) {
        if (e.target.id.localeCompare("Username") === 0) {
            username = e.target.value;

        }  else if (e.target.id.localeCompare("Email") === 0) {
            email = e.target.value;
        }  else if (e.target.id.localeCompare("Password") === 0) {
            password = e.target.value;
        }
    }

    async function handleSubmit() {
        alert(email);
        alert(password);
        try {
            await AuthentificationService.addUser({
                username: username;
            })  .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose} TransitionComponent={Transition}>
                <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose} aria-label="close">
                            <CloseIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                            New User
                        </Typography>
                        <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => {
                            handleSubmit();
                            handleClose();
                        }}>
                            YES
                        </Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <List>
                    <ListItem button>
                        <TextField className="fontLogin"
                                   onChange={textFieldChange}
                                   label="Username"
                                   style={{width: '55%'}}
                                   id="Username"
                        />
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I would like to call handleClickOpen of this file but in the other file.

When i call it, i get the error "doesn't exist".

I imported my file so why doesn't he find it ?

Maybe it is in a different class so should i have getter or something like that ?

What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

Some initial thoughts:

It looks like you're exporting a lot of functionality all inside of your 'export'.  Have you tried moving the functionality, and then exporting the file itself, instead of exporting the functions?

Also, handleClickOpen() is written inside of FullScreenDialogue(). That makes me think that to invoke it, you're going to have to first invoke FullScreenDialogue --- you wouldn't be able to invoke handleClickOpen as a standalone function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function `handleClickOpen` belongs to the `FullScreenDialog` class, so you should import this class:

```
import FullScreenDialog from "./ModifyUser";
```

Secondly, the `handleClickOpen` function manages a state of a component that must be rendered somewhere in order to call its functions. If you want to call this function before component is rendered (or to trigger component rendering), you can try making this function `static` but then you can't use `this` context from the function (which includes component's state).

Comment: Okay, thanks, but I can't put the function as static